# Primary Key Field Problem - Violation of Primary Key Constraint' PK_MyTable_179AOAFE03317E3D' Cannot Insert..?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008. When I save by First_Click of Save button its saving no problem. Suppose if I reclick the save button again I am getting the above error. So how to solve this type of problems?

I have a field primary key MyPrimField.

And I am getting the data using the following code:

```
DataTable ChkClone = MyDtb1.Clone();
DataRow[] MyCloneRow = MyDtb1.Select("door_no is not null");

foreach (DataRow DaR in MyCloneRow)
{
    ChkClone.ImportRow(DaR);
}
```

Comment: Why don't you add a flag, set it to true when you call the method and if someone clicks again you check the flag and ignore the rest of the method

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I did ado.net, but from your code it looks like ChkClone is the same as MyDtb1 (since you're doing a clone.)

Then in your for loop, you're trying to import a row into the data table, but it already exists.